# Any irreversible damage from not treating common cold right

Tags: common-cold, influenza, irreversible-damage

When I catch a cold, I usually just work through it, i.e. take no rest day and try to live by the same schedule as when I'm healthy.

I already read on WebMD that this behaviour can increase the duration of the cold and / or worsen the symptoms, but can I also experience any *long-term* damage, e.g. from the additional ~3 days of coughing?

And how about when the common cold symptoms mix with flu symptoms?

Comment: I would strongly recommend - in the interest of your co-workers, family and friends - to take a day off when you have a strong cold. I pull through with minor ones too (if you have no more than a running nose). But it is unethical to go to office and give your co-workers the cold. Furthermore, I myself can get really edgy if I'm sick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common colds are exactly that, common. Lots of people contract colds and there are no significant health repercussions. http://www.nhs.uk/Livewell/coldsandflu/Pages/Coldcomfort.aspx However, if you have underlying medical conditions where your immune system is already compromised then a common cold can cause serious problems if left untreated. 
If you have a serious underlying health condition, your doctor will likely advise you of what action to take should you contract a cold.

Comment: Same as with the other answers: Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that **all answers** should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) in order to provide the community with the means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help].

Comment: I am sorry for my lack of reliable reference. Perhaps this http://www.nhs.uk/Livewell/coldsandflu/Pages/Coldcomfort.aspx would help?

Comment: Currently, my vote is locked. If you [edit] your answer and include your reference, the system will allow me to reverse my vote and turn it into a +1, which you definitely deserve!